# If statement not returning value in razor

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-webpages

I attempting to get a numeric value to be returned from a database using linq in razor. 
When I attempt nothing is being returned. Here is an example of my what i did. The variable which is not printing is the "grad_year"

```
@{
    var trust = new trusteeEntities();
    var former = (from g in trust.Members
                where g.status == "Former"
                orderby g.lname ascending
                select g);
    var pos = 0;
    foreach (var f in former)
    {
        <div class="member">
            <h6>@f.fname @f.lname @if (f.grad_year != null) { @string.Format("'{0:00}", f.grad_year); }  @if (f.deceased == true){@Html.Raw("**")}</h6>
       </div>
    }                      
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say there was one variable not printing. Which is the grad_year. Everything else prints out. @GrantWinney

Comment: BTW that code probably belongs in a controller.

Comment: @James would the fact that I am using it a macroscript make a difference?

Comment: Is this MVC or is the Webpages v2?

Comment: What is type of that `grad_year` (badly named for public sample) property?

Comment: web pages v2 @ErikPhilips

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov grad_year is of type numeric

Comment: There is no `numeric` type in C#...

Comment: the grad_year is being pulled from the db @alexeiLevenkov

Comment: Not sure, but try without the ';' after string.Format. I think it makes the difference between an expression (printed by razor) and a statement.

Comment: @jods that returned an error unfortunately

Comment: I was wondering if " string.Format()" makes a difference since i am trying to output a numeric value

Comment: just try first without the format

Comment: I did that and it printed the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably not getting outputted because it is just executing the 'string.Format(..)' as a statement.

You have to explicity tell the Razor engine to output it.

This can be done by putting [<text></text>](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) around it, e.g.

```
@if (f.grad_year != null) { <text>@string.Format("'{0:00}", f.grad_year)</text> }
```

---

Edit:

You could also do this with the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), e.g.

```
@(f.grad_year != null ? @string.Format("'{0:00}", f.grad_year) : null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only logical conclusion is that your collection of `former` is empty (Count == 0) and thus your enumeration is not executed. Determine why the collection is empty to verify.